# c# Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Tags: c#

When I execute the following query, I get the error message `date is incompatible with int`:

```
textBox4.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();

DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();

cmd.CommandText = "select ID_REPAS FROM CONSOMMER C , GROUPE G WHERE G.REF_GROUPE=C.REF_GROUPE AND C.dateEFF=G.dateEff and G.REF_GROUPE=" + textBox3.Text + "and C.dateEFF=" +dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
da2.Fill(ds1, "idrepas");

textBox2.Text = ds1.Tables["idrepas"].Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

Comment: which line is causing the problem, and what is your question?

Comment: date is incompatible with int in this line : and C.dateEFF=" +dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString()

Comment: Can you show some effort yourself, e.g. by narrowing down the problem through eliminating potential error sources. Also, *where* is the error pointing to? The compiler should give you a location. Please point that out in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearest and safest way is to use SQL parameters...

```
cmd.CommandText = "select ID_REPAS FROM CONSOMMER C , GROUPE G WHERE G.REF_GROUPE=C.REF_GROUPE AND C.dateEFF=G.dateEff and G.REF_GROUPE=@txtBox3Val and C.dateEFF=@shortDate";

command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("txtBox3Val" , textBox3.Text));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("shortDate", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString());
```

Which helps to avoid hard to manage tack ('+') together code and prevents injections attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting single quotes around your date string (the numbers in the date string are being treated like an integer otherwise):

```
... + "and C.dateEFF='" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString() + "'";
```

Comment: Note that the code is not good - it's vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Not that vulnerable actually. There is no free input processing